# django allauth adding uuid field

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm trying to add a field for user uuid for sigup but after adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser"`

I'm getting errors even without makemigrations and with makemigrations too. I deleted all migrations and drop the database and I created new database :

If I comment this line :

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser"
```

I get error :

```
hook : register_rich_text_handlers
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 546, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
aihuser.AihUser.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'aihuser.AihUser.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'aihuser.AihUser.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.
aihuser.AihUser.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'aihuser.AihUser.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'aihuser.AihUser.user_permissions' or 'auth.User.user_permissions'.
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'aihuser.AihUser.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.groups' or 'aihuser.AihUser.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'aihuser.AihUser.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'auth.User.user_permissions' or 'aihuser.AihUser.user_permissions'.

System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
```

If I uncomment the line :

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser"

I get this error :

```
Wagtail version is : 4.1.9
DEV environment
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/utils.py", line 174, in get_field_parts
    opts = field.remote_field.model._meta
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 398, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/snippets/apps.py", line 16, in ready
    register_deferred_snippets()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/snippets/models.py", line 142, in register_deferred_snippets
    _register_snippet_immediately(model, viewset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/snippets/models.py", line 74, in _register_snippet_immediately
    from wagtail.snippets.views.snippets import SnippetViewSet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail/snippets/views/snippets.py", line 628, in <module>
    class SnippetHistoryReportFilterSet(WagtailFilterSet):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 62, in __new__
    new_class.base_filters = new_class.get_filters()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/filterset.py", line 325, in get_filters
    field = get_model_field(cls._meta.model, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/utils.py", line 144, in get_model_field
    fields = get_field_parts(model, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django_filters/utils.py", line 179, in get_field_parts
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Unable to resolve relationship `user` for `wagtailcore.ModelLogEntry`. Django is most likely not initialized, and its apps registry not populated. Ensure Django has finished setup before loading `FilterSet`s.
```

In my setting I have aihuser in installed apps :

## wg_aihalbum_04/wg_aihalbum_04/settings/base.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # default apps
    'wagtail_modeltranslation',
    'wagtail_modeltranslation.makemigrations',
    'wagtail_modeltranslation.migrate',

    'colorfield',
    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.contrib.settings',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.locales',
    'wagtail.contrib.routable_page',
    'wagtail.contrib.sitemaps',
    'captcha',
    'wagtailcaptcha',
    'wagtail',
    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin',
    'rest_framework',

    # default apps
    'apps.home',
    'apps.search',
    'apps.front',
    'apps.site_settings',
    'apps.menus',
    'apps.flex',
    'apps.newsletter',

    # Authentication
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    # AIH APPS
    'apps.aihuser',
    # 'apps.aihalbum',
    # 'apps.aihprofile',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',

    # AIH APPS
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]

# Allauth specific settings

# Authentication Backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

# AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser" 

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username_email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username_email"
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'optional'  # Can be 'optional' or 'none'
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_PASSWORD_RESET = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'
ACCOUNT_PRESERVE_USERNAME_CASING = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = ["admin", "god"]
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_MIN_LENGTH = 2


ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'apps.forms.AihuserSignupForm',
}
```

I deleted everything and start project from beggining :

## wg_aihalbum_04/apps/aihuser/forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from .models import *
from collections import OrderedDict
import uuid

class AihuserSignupForm(SignupForm):
    
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(AihuserSignupForm, self).save(request)
        user.uuid = uuid.uuid4()  # Generate a new UUID
        user.save()
        return user
```

## wg_aihalbum_04/apps/aihuser/models.py :

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class AihUser(AbstractUser):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
```

## pip list :

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ -----------
anyascii                 0.3.1
asgiref                  3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo       0.2.1
beautifulsoup4           4.11.1
certifi                  2022.12.7
cffi                     1.16.0
charset-normalizer       2.1.1
cryptography             41.0.7
defusedxml               0.7.1
Django                   4.1.4
django-allauth           0.58.2
django-anymail           9.0
django-autoslug          1.9.8
django-colorfield        0.8.0
django-debug-toolbar     4.1.0
django-extensions        3.2.1
django-filter            22.1
django-modelcluster      6.0
django-modeltranslation  0.18.7
django-permissionedforms 0.1
django-recaptcha         3.0.0
django-robots            6.1
django-taggit            3.1.0
django-treebeard         4.5.1
djangorestframework      3.14.0
djongo                   1.3.6
dnspython                2.4.2
draftjs-exporter         2.1.7
et-xmlfile               1.1.0
html5lib                 1.1
idna                     3.4
l18n                     2021.3
mongoengine              0.27.0
oauthlib                 3.2.2
openpyxl                 3.0.10
Pillow                   9.3.0
pip                      23.3.2
psycopg2-binary          2.9.5
pycparser                2.21
PyJWT                    2.8.0
pymongo                  3.12.3
python3-openid           3.2.0
pytz                     2022.6
requests                 2.28.1
requests-oauthlib        1.3.1
setuptools               45.1.0
six                      1.16.0
soupsieve                2.3.2.post1
sqlparse                 0.2.4
telepath                 0.3
typing_extensions        4.4.0
urllib3                  1.26.13
wagtail                  4.1.9
wagtail-django-recaptcha 1.0
wagtail-modeltranslation 0.14.0
wagtail-robots           0.4.0
webencodings             0.5.1
wheel                    0.34.2
Willow                   1.4.1
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser"` be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "apps.aihuser.UidUser"` in your settings file?  General suggestions: clear migration files if you haven't already even though you've deleted the db, they may still contain outdated code. Comment out AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser" and try migrating to see if the issue is with the custom model. Check if order of apps declared in your installed apps is correct, sometimes they need to be in a specific order.

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = "apps.aihuser.UidUser" return :

`Invalid model reference 'apps.aihuser.UidUser'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

Comment: do you have an __init__.py file in your apps directory?

Comment: and try placing 'apps.aihuser', at the top of the list

Comment: yes I have init.py I placed at teh top and still the problem exist

Answer (score 0):

Your settings file user configuration should match the actual path to the custom user model, or Django won't be able to find it. It currently is looking in the base dir for aihuser app which according to your declared apps in the settings file does not exist as aihuser is stored in an apps directory instead, so:

change this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser"` to reflect the actual path to your user model, most likely `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "apps.aihuser.UidUser"`.

Comment: AUTH_USER_MODEL = "apps.aihuser.UidUser" return :

`Invalid model reference 'apps.aihuser.UidUser'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.`

Comment: still having the same error

Comment: change the line back to AUTH_USER_MODEL = "aihuser.UidUser" and place 'apps.aihuser', above the album and profile lines since I'm guessing they reference your custom user so the user needs to be declared Before they can access it. if it doesn't work, report back the error messsage

Comment: I did the change; python manage.py makemigrations return :
`ValueError: The field account.EmailAddress.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'aihuser.uiduser', but app 'aihuser' isn't installed.
The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'aihuser.uiduser', but app 'aihuser' isn't installed.
The field socialaccount.SocialAccount.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'aihuser.uiduser', but app 'aihuser' isn't installed.
The field wagtailcore.Comment.resolved_by was declared with a lazy reference to 'aihuser.uiduser', but app 'aihuser' isn't installed....`

Comment: Please update the code snippets you provided above too so that I can see them. Specifically, update all the snippets that you've changed since you posted the question including the list of apps declared in the settings file.

Comment: the question updated

Comment: okasy, let's start over. To avoid a number of issues, I would suggest you delete that app entirely and start over. First drop db and delete all migration files except init files in each app that depends on your user model ** Important** by this I mean EVERY app in your project that involves a user field/model reference. 2. make sure you use 'python manage.py startapp aihuser' to start the app. 3. Include the app in installed_apps section of your settings. 4. declare your custom user-- address the related_name conflicts noted above. 5. run migrations and report back if any erorrs persist

Comment: I did create a new project and updated the question with codes and errors can you check that please

Comment: Post the output of this command "pip list" making sure you run it in your python environmet for the project.

Comment: I add a list show from pip list